# Why the User data are not updated? in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a Model called UserAccount,
I have tried several ways to update the data for an existing user, it responds that changes are successful without any error but still nothing is reflecting in Database

Here is the Model

```
class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email"),validators=[EmailValidator()],unique=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{12}$', 'Enter a valid phone number.')])
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/users_photos/%Y/%m',null=True,blank=True)
    employee_id = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(999)], null=True,blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True , null=True)

    objects = CustomUserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name","phone"]
    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"

    class Role(models.TextChoices):
        ADMIN = "Admin", "Admin"
        MANAGER = "Manager", "manager"
        NORMALUSER = "Normal", "normaluser"

    base_role = Role.NORMALUSER

    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Role.choices)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.role = self.base_role
            return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.first_name and self.last_name:
            fullname = f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'
        elif self.first_name:
            fullname = self.first_name
        elif self.last_name:
            fullname = self.last_name
        else:
            fullname = "Unnamed User"
        return fullname


    # Add related_name to avoid clashes
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Group',
        related_name='user_accounts',
        blank=True,
        help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.',
        verbose_name='groups',
    )
    user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
        'auth.Permission',
        related_name='user_accounts',
        blank=True,
        help_text='Specific permissions for this user.',
        verbose_name='user permissions',
    )

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email
```

Here is theForm

```
class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone', 'profile_picture', 'employee_id']
```

Here is the View

```
def edit_ni_user(request , user_id):

    request_user = get_object_or_404(UserAccount,id=user_id)
    edit_user_form = EditUserForm()


    if request.method == "POST":
        edit_user_form =EditUserForm(request.POST, request.FILES , instance=request_user)
        if edit_user_form.is_valid():
            print("edit_user_form is valid")

            newfirst_name = edit_user_form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            newlast_name = edit_user_form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            newphone = edit_user_form.cleaned_data['phone']
            newprofile_picture = edit_user_form.cleaned_data['profile_picture']
            newemployeeid = edit_user_form.cleaned_data['employee_id']

            request_user.first_name = newfirst_name
            request_user.last_name = newlast_name
            request_user.phone = newphone
            request_user.profile_picture = newprofile_picture
            request_user.employee_id= newemployeeid
            request_user.email = request_user.email
            request_user.save()
  
            print(get_object_or_404(UserAccount,id=user_id))

            print(UserAccount.objects.filter(id = request_user.pk).first())
            messages.success(request, f" {request_user}  Edited Successfully")

            return redirect('index')
        else:
            # Iterate over form errors and add appropriate messages
            for field, errors in edit_user_form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                     messages.error(request, f'{field}: {error}')
    elif request.method=="GET":

        edit_user_form = EditUserForm(instance = request_user)
```

every attempt are showing the success message in the content in the msg are the updated data but its not saved in the Database
am using PostgreSQL v 15

Comment: Please try to pare this down to a [mre] - this is a lot of code to sift through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.save()` method only calls the `super().save()` in case the item is not created. You need to do that in both scenario's, so:

```
class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    # …

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.role = self.base_role
        # not in if case
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```